# module 'Crypto.publickey' has no attribute RSA

Tags: python

I have installed the package pycryptodome . When I use it like this:

```
import Crypto.publickey
Crypto.publickey.RSA.importKey(base64.b64decode(PRIVATE_KEY))
```

It gives me a error:module 'Crypto.publickey' has no attribute RSA
then I change my code:

```
import Crypto.publickey.RSA
```

It works.
Why? I'm confused.